# Non-admin users can't reach Reports

Tags: vtiger

We use vtiger 7 in the office and I faced the serious problem. I don' know what to do. If I entered with admin role, the 'Reports' icon works, and vtiger lists all the reports. Non-admin users after click the 'Reports' get a white blank screen only. Everything else works.

Anybody knows the solution?

Comment: That's weird; the same question was asked word-for-word identically and answered elsewhere [a year ago](https://discussions.vtiger.com/discussion/185588/non-admin-users-cant-reach-reports).

Answer (score 0):

go to Database. Get a backup of database. run the following queries in database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vtiger_report_sharerole` (
`reportid` int(25) NOT NULL,
`roleid` int(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vtiger_report_sharers` (
`reportid` int(25) NOT NULL,
`rsid` int(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```